# Different partition after upgrade of OPENWRT

Tags: filesystems, partition, openwrt

I have just updated the firmware of my olinuxino rt5350f to the last release of chaos calmer 15.05.1 ([website](https://openwrt.org/), [image](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/rt305x/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-rt305x-olinuxino-rt5350f-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin)).

After having finished the installation via tftp I noticed that the free space is now just 232 KB, while it was 2 MB with the previous version. Is there any module or packet that has been added and that I can remove. Do you think I did something wrong? Is it possible to change the size of any partition?
On the current version of chaos calmer 15.05.1 when I type `df -h` I obtain:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs 448.0K 216.0K 232.0K 48% /
/dev/root 2.3M 2.3M 0 100% /rom
tmpfs 14.2M 624.0K 13.6M 4% /tmp
tmpfs 14.2M 48.0K 14.2M 0% /tmp/root
tmpfs 512.0K 0 512.0K 0% /dev
/dev/mtdblock6 448.0K 216.0K 232.0K 48% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay 448.0K 216.0K 232.0K 48% /
```

On the previous version instead:

```
root@OpenWrt:/# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs 4.2M 2.1M 2.1M 50% /
/dev/root 2.5M 2.5M 0 100% /rom
tmpfs 14.3M 432.0K 13.8M 3% /tmp
/dev/mtdblock6 4.2M 2.1M 2.1M 50% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay 4.2M 2.1M 2.1M 50% /
tmpfs 512.0K 0 512.0K 0% /dev
```